# Should i use Acetone on the walls before painting?

Tags: painting

Can i use Acetone on my bedroom walls before painting with Latex satin? I washed walls in another room with soap and water, painted the walls. When i took off the frog tape 1 hour later, the paint came off with it. It was like the paint had turned to plastic. Help!

Comment: I think the tape must come off when the paint is still wet. Otherwise the paint will form a continuous film over the boundary and it will pull off the paint on surface being painted.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use a primer.**

A latex primer will help the latex paint adhere to the wall. The latex paint may not be sticking if there is too much soap left over on the wall. A primer will stick a lot easier and the latex paint will stick to that without issue.

Since it only takes an hour (though you should probably wait longer than the minimum time), you might also try making sure there is no soap left over on the wall. If it's still failing, I'd go with a latex primer.

To directly answer the question: No; you should not use acetone.

Answer (score 2):

TSP (Tri Sodium Phosphate) or TSP substitute will clean any residue from your wall and make your top coat adhere better.  Between that and using a latex primer, you can recoat just about anything.

For nastier stains and oil paint, you can use an oil primer like Kilz.  The fumes are pretty rough, but it will seal anything you can imagine and prep the surface for a color coat.

Acetone tends to dissolve latex paint, so you'll have some finish problems and need to neutralize it or let it evaporate.  It's pretty nasty stuff to use, as well.